# Possible sybase/ansi transact sql query for these requirements

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I'm trying to figure out the transact sql for the following problem (for sybase) which is my question. Given the following tables and data:

Table: bank_rating

```
| bank_name | agency   |
| BankA     | Marvel   |
| BankA     | Sullivan |
| BankA     | Fargo    |
| BankB     | Marvel   |
| BankB     | Fargo    |
```

Table: agency_rating

```
| agency | rating |
| Marvel | 1      |
| Short  | 1      |
| Fargo  | 2      |
```

I need to do the following.

Populate a new table with data (example below):

Table: results_table

```
| bank_name | agency |
| BankA     | Marvel |
```

such that:

- I always pick the agency that has the lowest rating.
- If two agencies have the same rating then pick the first agency alphabetically.

The bit that I'm struggling with is how to choose the agency with the lowest rating but if the rating is the same then to select the first one alphabetically.

What is the transact sql for this problem given the intended database of sybase?

Would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: what version of sybase?  Do you have access to windowing functions?

Comment: @bluefeet I don't have access to sybase yet but am trying to learn the syntax so I don't know. I'm having to test on a different db locally. If you are so inclined it would be very helpful for me to see both alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select * from
(
  select b.bank_name, a.agency,
  rank() over (partition by b.bank_name order by a.rating, b.agency) rnk
  from bank_rating b
  inner join agency_rating a on b.agency = a.agency
)
where rnk = 1
```

To create new table you can do

```
Select bank_name, agency into result_table from
(
  select b.bank_name, a.agency,
  rank() over (partition by b.bank_name order by a.rating, b.agency) rnk
  from bank_rating b
  inner join agency_rating a on b.agency = a.agency
)
where rnk = 1
```

To insert into existing table

```
insert into result_table(bank_name, agency)
Select bank_name, agency from
(
  select b.bank_name, a.agency,
  rank() over (partition by b.bank_name order by a.rating, b.agency) rnk
  from bank_rating b
  inner join agency_rating a on b.agency = a.agency
)
where rnk = 1
```

Without using windowing functions:

```
select bank_name, a.agency
from bank_rating b
outer apply (select top 1 y.agency
             from  bank_rating y
             inner join agency_rating x on y.agency = x.agency
             where y.bank_name = b.bank_name
             order by x.rating, x.agency) a
```

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the population into the new results table is that just a case of INSERT INTO results_table SELECT * FROM ... ?

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity can this be done without using windowing functions as @bluefeet was referring to?

Comment: Wow very comprehensive answer. That last one has quite a few things for me to learn. Interesting how you refer to the outer select from the inner one. The 'top 1' and 'outer apply' usage is also new to me. Thanks.